# Using ClassLoader for file dependency loading; not working if files are in subdirectory

Tags: java, url, resources, classloader

I am using the code:

URL c = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(filename);

to get a path to a text file. It works fine when in the directory src/main/resources. However, it returns null if I attempt to put it in a subdirectory. How can I get the class loader to look in subdirectories?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the kicks:
Did you try `ClassLoader.getSystemResource(subDir + "/" + filename);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the relative path name.  It won't search the directories recursively for you as this is expensive and error prone.  You would not know what you would get if you had two resources with the same name in different directories.